# matlab and matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, math

Got one more problem with matrix multiplication in Matlab. I have to plot Taylor polynomials for the given function. This question is similar to my previous one (but this time, the function is `f: R^2 -> R^3`) and I can't figure out how to make the matrices in order to make it work...

```
function example
   clf;
   M = 40; 
   N = 20; 

   % domain of f(x)
   x1 = linspace(0,2*pi,M).'*ones(1,N); 
   x2 = ones(M,1)*linspace(0,2*pi,N);

   [y1,y2,y3] = F(x1,x2); 
   mesh(y1,y2,y3,...
     'facecolor','w',...
     'edgecolor','k');
   axis equal; 
   axis vis3d; 
   axis manual; 
   hold on

   % point for our Taylor polynom
   xx1 = 3; 
   xx2 = 0.5; 
   [yy1,yy2,yy3] = F(xx1,xx2); 

   % plots one discrete point
   plot3(yy1,yy2,yy3,'ro'); 

   [y1,y2,y3] = T1(xx1,xx2,x1,x2); 
   mesh(y1,y2,y3,...
     'facecolor','w',...
     'edgecolor','g');


% given function
function [y1,y2,y3] = F(x1,x2)
   % constants
   R=2; r=1; 

   y1 = (R+r*cos(x2)).*cos(x1);
   y2 = (R+r*cos(x2)).*sin(x1);
   y3 = r*sin(x2);

function [y1,y2,y3] = T1(xx1,xx2,x1,x2)
   dy = [
     -(R + r*cos(xx2))*sin(xx1) -r*cos(xx1)*sin(xx2) 
      (R + r*cos(xx2))*cos(xx1) -r*sin(xx1)*sin(xx2) 
                              0  r*cos(xx2)          ];
   y = F(xx1, xx2) + dy.*[x1-xx1; x2-xx2];

function [y1,y2,y3] = T2(xx1,xx2,x1,x2)
% ?
```

I know that my code is full of mistakes (I just need to fix my T1 function). `dy` represents Jacobian matrix (total derivation of `f(x)` - I hope I got it right...). I am not sure how would the Hessian matrix in `T2` look, by I hope I will figure it out, I'm just lost in Matlab...

**edit**: I tried to improve my formatting - here's my Jacobian matrix

```
[-(R + r*cos(xx2))*sin(xx1), -r*cos(xx1)*sin(xx2)...
  (R + r*cos(xx2))*cos(xx1), -r*sin(xx1)*sin(xx2)...
  0,                          r*cos(xx2)];
```

Comment: Try improving your formatting. Make your code readable if you want help on it. It will help you in the future too. Don't have many lines in one. Whitespace is FREE!!!! Use comments. They too will help you as much as it helps someone who tries to read your code. Use intelligent variable names. Extra characters in names are also free! They cost you nothing except a second to type. But your lost debugging time will cost you far more than that when you need to figure out what in the name of god and little green apples yy1 refers to.

Comment: DON'T Name your function display. Doing silly things like this will cause you MANY problems, since an existing function called display is already in MATLAB. By the way, had I not said this, your next question on SOFlow would have been why does my code not work as I expect it to work?

Comment: I have modified the Jacobian so that it is both valid Matlab syntax and readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [y1,y2,y3]=T1(xx1,xx2,x1,x2)
    R=2; r=1;
    %derivatives
    y1dx1 = -(R + r * cos(xx2)) * sin(xx1);
    y1dx2 = -r * cos(xx1) * sin(xx2);
    y2dx1 = (R + r * cos(xx2)) * cos(xx1);
    y2dx2 = -r * sin(xx1) * sin(xx2);
    y3dx1 = 0;
    y3dx2 = r * cos(xx2);
    %T1
    [f1, f2, f3] = F(xx1, xx2);
    y1 = f1 + y1dx1*(x1-xx1) + y1dx2*(x2-xx2);
    y2 = f2 + y2dx1*(x1-xx1) + y2dx2*(x2-xx2);
    y3 = f3 + y3dx1*(x1-xx1) + y3dx2*(x2-xx2);
```